# Quote positioning on a long sarcastic-explanation phrase

Tags: punctuation, quotation-marks, compound-adjectives

In the following excerpt, would it be more correct to close the quotation after "pose"?

> ...and they stand in the ISO-standard "security man waiting for you to walk through the door so he can escort you" pose by the door.

(Also, is there a better word for what I did there with the quotes, since "sarcastic" doesn't really fit?)

Comment: Can you provide a larger extract? It's not clear what the meaning, or indeed the tone, is.

Comment: I think "sarcastic" is a pretty good description of this type of adjective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it would **not** it be more correct to close the quotation after "pose".

If you were to omit the quoted expression you will have:

> ...and they stand in the ISO-standard ... pose by the door.

which makes grammatical sense, even though you may not understand an *ISO-standard pose*.
On the other hand, if you were to include *pose* within the quotation, omitting the quotation would give you:

> ...and they stand in the ISO-standard ... by the door.

which is **not** grammatical (or you are left wondering what is *the ISO-standard* in which they are standing!).

Answer (score 6):

No, it wouldn't be more correct, and in fact I'd argue it would be wrong. The phrase "security man waiting for you to walk through the door so he can escort you" is a parenthetical, and *pose* is not part of it, but rather the head of the entire noun phrase "ISO-standard 'security man waiting for you to walk through the door so he can escort you' pose". For all intents and purposes, you can regard *ISO-standard* and *security man waiting for you to walk through the door so he can escort you* as two adjectives on equal footing. Which is also the reason you could see both of them hyphenated rather than one of them enclosed in quotes, i.e. "the ISO-standard security-man-waiting-for-you-to-walk-through-the-door-so-he-can-escort-you pose".

Answer (score 2):

Try dashes instead of quotes since the phrase is very long:

> ...and they stand by the door in the ISO-standard
>   ***security-man-waiting-for-you-to-walk-through-the-door-so-he-can-escort-you***
>   pose.

Also, I put "by the door" up front so that you don't get that dangling prepositional phrase so far from the subject. :-)

And . . . not that you asked for an alternative phrase, but @fumblefingers comment is well taken.  You probably could shorten that bit to:

> ...and they stand by the door in the ISO-standard
>   ***security-man-escort***
>   pose.

Comment: +1 I think using dashes instead of quotes is an excellent way of making it easier for the reader to see he's got a (facetiously?) long (effectively, *parenthetical*) phrase coming up. In speech, you'd almost certainly speak those words more quickly than normal (if only so your audience didn't get bored and walk away before you'd finished! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers In fact, RegDwighт suggested dashes 2 hours earlier!

Comment: @TrevorD: I freely admit I was something of a "drive-by upvoter" there. I'd already upvoted Reg's answer before this one, but I hadn't actually read it all the way to the end. I just upvoted because he said it would be wrong to include the word "pose" in the quotes. Anyway, although I think strictly speaking it's Off Topic advice on writing style, Kristina's point about putting *by the door* before the ensuing "linguistic obstacle course" is [sound as a pound](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/sound+as+a+pound.html), as we Brits say.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, guilty of the same thing!  I didn't see RegDwight's dashes at the bottom of the answer.  Thanks! :-)

Comment: @ Kristina: Perhaps Reg isn't the maestro we thought he was! We both missed it because it was a *second* point being made in a relatively long paragraph. A paragraph made orthographically much longer than the semantic content would ordinarily imply, simply because it includes that entire parenthetical phrase ***four*** times (is anyone gonna be brave/cheeky enough to edit a line-break into the middle of his answer? :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Not I!  He threw a friend of mine off of the site and banished her ID for posting a question with a hidden message to me. lol!  (Rightfully so, actually.)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the opening quotation mark may be misplaced, too.

That is, *they stand in the ISO-standard "security man ... escort you" pose* means that somebody unnamed is impersonating, conventionally, a security man waiting to &c.

But it may be that what is intended is the security men are standing in a pose which is conventional in their profession, which I would point this way:

> they stand in the ISO-standard security man "waiting ... escort you" pose

Comment: You've quite a muddle there.  That is, the point isn't made clear.  The dog's breakfast mix of bracketed and parenthetical phrases clutters the picture as well.  Perhaps break the second sentence into four shorter sentences.

Comment: @jwpat7 Point well taken. I've rewritten

Comment: It now reads as if the security man is of *ISO-standard*, rather then it being the pose that is *ISO-standard*. I read is as if the pose is the type of pose adopted by a *security man waiting [to] escort you*.  There is no *impersonation* implied in the original question, merely that the pose is the type of pose that a security man might use.